# C++ Qt slot connect error error C2665 on QComboBox::currentIndexChanged

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

Visual Studio says that here is error C2665. But why? I am 100% sure that my code is correct. QComboBox has signal currentIndexChanged that takes only one int argument. I have a slot that takes only one int argument. So what is the problem to connect them?

```
 //Defined in ui_MyDialog.h
QComboBox *messageType;

...

//Constructor of MyDialog
connect(ui.messageType, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, this, &MyDialog::IndexChanged, Qt::QueuedConnection);

...

//Prototype of signal in MyDialog class definition
public slots:
    void IndexChanged(int index);

...

//Definition of IndexChanged signal
void MyDialog::IndexChanged(int index)
{

}
```

error text:

```
1>MyDialog.cpp(61,119): error C2665: QObject::connect: none of the 3 overloads can convert all argument types
1>F:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qobject.h(225,36): message : can be "QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const QMetaMethod &,const QObject *,const QMetaMethod &,Qt::ConnectionType)" (source file MyDialog.cpp is compiled)
1>F:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qobject.h(222,36): message : or "QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject * ,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)" (compiles source file MyDialog.cpp)
1>MyDialog.cpp(61,5): message : "QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)": cannot convert argument 2 from "overloaded-function" to "const char *"
1>MyDialog.cpp(61,41): message : Context does not allow overloaded function disambiguation
1>F:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qobject.h(222,36): message : see "QObject::connect" declaration (source file MyDialog.cpp is compiled)
1>MyDialog.cpp(61,119): message : when trying to match argument list "(QComboBox *, overloaded-function, MyDialog *, void (__cdecl MyDialog::* )(int), Qt::ConnectionType)"
```

Comment: error C2665: QObject::connect: none of the 3 overloads can convert all argument types

Comment: What type is `ui.messageType`?  We really need to see a [mcve].

Comment: Make it `QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged)`. There are several overloads of `currentIndexChanged` taking different parameters; the compiler doesn't know which one you mean to take the address of.

Comment: Added more info to  question post.

Comment: QOverload<int>::of() Really works. It helped. This is very strange bug-like behaviour. There is only two versions of this signal, QString and int. There is no ambiguous definitions. Why compiler says that it cannot solve this I have no idea. But thanks, that helped.

Comment: @ivanbiba Given the context in which `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged` is being used here, how would the compiler know which overload to select?

Comment: I thought it compares it with slot arguments signature somehow, but now I got it. Thanks. Compiler don't know anything about "signals" and "slots" when we use function pointers and links with existing overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler doesn't know anything about slots and signals so it don't compare slot signature wth signal signature. If some slot or signal has overloads link or pointer to this slot will be ambiguous. To avoid that we need to specify explicitly what overloaded method we are using here, using `QOverload`.

Correct way to connect this signal:

```
connect(ui.messageType, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, &MyDialog::IndexChanged, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```